# Reddit and Twitter bot in Python using PRAW

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, bots, reddit

I am a beginner in Python, and trying out making a bot which automatically Tweets anything which is posted on a Subreddit that I have made.

I took help from some of the tutorials online which has the following code

```
import praw
import json
import requests
import tweepy
import time

access_token = '************************************'
access_token_secret = '************************************'
consumer_key = '************************************'
consumer_secret = '************************************'

def strip_title(title):
    if len(title) == 94:
        return title
    else:
        return title[:93] + "..."

def tweet_creator(subreddit_info):
    post_dict = {}
    post_ids = []
    print("[bot] Getting posts from Reddit")
    for submission in subreddit_info.get_hot(limit=20):
        post_dict[strip_title(submission.title)] = submission.url
        post_ids.append(submission.id)
    print("[bot] Generating short link using goo.gl")
    mini_post_dict = {}
    for post in post_dict:
        post_title = post
        post_link = post_dict[post]
        short_link = shorten(post_link)
        mini_post_dict[post_title] = short_link
    return mini_post_dict, post_ids

def setup_connection_reddit(subreddit):
    print("[bot] setting up connection with Reddit")
    r = praw.Reddit(' %s' %(subreddit))
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(subreddit)
    return subreddit

def shorten(url):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {"longUrl": url}
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    link = json.loads(r.text)['id']
    return link

def duplicate_check(id):
    found = 0
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if id in line:
                found = 1
    return found


def add_id_to_file(id):
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(id) + "\n")

def main():
    subreddit = setup_connection_reddit('*Name of the subreddit*')
    post_dict, post_ids = tweet_creator(subreddit)
    tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)

def tweeter(post_dict, post_ids):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    for post, post_id in zip(post_dict, post_ids):
        found = duplicate_check(post_id)
        if found == 0:
            print("[bot] Posting this link on twitter")
            print(post + " " + post_dict[post] + " #Python #reddit #bot")
            api.update_status(post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #Python #reddit #bot")
            add_id_to_file(post_id)
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print("[bot] Already posted")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code seems fine in PyCharm, however I am getting the following error when I try to run it directly from the folder via Terminal using the rolling code, reddit_bot2.py is my file name:

```
 python3 reddit_bot2.py
```

When I try to run the code I am getting the following error:

```
mahesh@Maheshs-MacBook-Air Atoms % python3 reddit_bot2.py
[bot] setting up connection with Reddit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 846, in items
d.update(self._sections[section])
KeyError: '**Name of the subreddit to fetch posts from**'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mahesh/Python_Bot/Atoms/reddit_bot2.py", line 82, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/mahesh/Python_Bot/Atoms/reddit_bot2.py", line 62, in main
subreddit = setup_connection_reddit('Bot167')
  File "/Users/mahesh/Python_Bot/Atoms/reddit_bot2.py", line 36, in setup_connection_reddit
    r = praw.Reddit(' %s' %(subreddit))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 227, in __init__
self.config = Config(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/config.py", line 85, in __init__
self.custom = dict(Config.CONFIG.items(site_name), **settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 849, in items
raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: ' Bot167'
You provided the name of a praw.ini configuration which does not exist.

For help with creating a Reddit instance, visit
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit_instance.html

For help on configuring PRAW, visit
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html
```

Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your `praw.ini` file located? It looks like PyCharm is finding it, but running it at the command line, it is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: Also note that the Google URL shortener API this code uses was retired several years ago, so I would not expect that to work.